# bug with modal window and desktop widget

Tags: qooxdoo

(sorry my english!)
I use a modal window within a Tabview's page.

Check this little [playground example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520tabview%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tabview.TabView()%253B%250D%250Adoc.add(tabview%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%25200%252C%2520right%253A%25200%252C%2520bottom%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520pageFirst%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tabview.Page(%2522First%2522)%253B%250D%250ApageFirst.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Grow())%253B%250D%250Atabview.add(pageFirst)%253B%250D%250Atabview.setSelection(%255BpageFirst%255D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520desktop%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Desktop()%253B%250D%250Adesktop.set(%257BblockerColor%253A%2520'black'%252C%2520blockerOpacity%253A%25200.3%257D)%253B%250D%250ApageFirst.add(desktop)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btn1%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Button%25201%2522)%253B%250D%250Adesktop.add(btn1%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252010%252C%2520top%253A%252010%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btn2%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Button%25202%2522)%253B%250D%250Adesktop.add(btn2%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252010%252C%2520top%253A%2520100%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btnModal%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Open%2520Modal%2522)%253B%250D%250AbtnModal.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509var%2520win%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Window()%253B%250D%250A%2509win.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Basic())%253B%250D%250A%2509win.setModal(true)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520btnClose%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Close%2520Modal%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnClose.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509win.destroy()%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509win.add(btnClose)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509desktop.add(win)%253B%250D%250A%2509win.center()%253B%250D%250A%2509win.open()%253B%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250Adesktop.add(btnModal%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252010%252C%2520top%253A%2520200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520pageSecond%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tabview.Page(%2522Second%2522)%253B%250D%250ApageSecond.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Canvas())%253B%250D%250Atabview.add(pageSecond)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btn3%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Button%25203%2522)%253B%250D%250ApageSecond.add(btn3%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%2520100%252C%2520top%253A%252010%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btn4%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Button%25204%2522)%253B%250D%250ApageSecond.add(btn4%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%2520100%252C%2520top%253A%2520100%257D)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D).

Open the modal window, go to Second page, and return to First page. How can i solve this problem with the opened modal window? I need switch to other pages, return to the modal window's page, and close the modal window.
I've been trying to figure this out. The Widget Browser application, from Qooxdoo website have the same problem, with the Window page example.

Thanks.

Comment: this is a bug; please can you file an issue at https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/issues?

Comment: can you file this issue at github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/issues. I dont have user, my english is bad, im angry, etc...

Answer (score 0):

this little modification work fine

[Playground example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520tabview%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tabview.TabView()%253B%250D%250Adoc.add(tabview%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%25200%252C%2520right%253A%25200%252C%2520bottom%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520pageFirst%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tabview.Page(%2522First%2522)%253B%250D%250ApageFirst.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Grow())%253B%250D%250Atabview.add(pageFirst)%253B%250D%250Atabview.setSelection(%255BpageFirst%255D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520desktop%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Desktop()%253B%250D%250ApageFirst.add(desktop)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520composite%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.container.Composite(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Canvas())%253B%250D%250Adesktop.add(composite%252C%2520%257Bedge%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520blocker%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.core.Blocker(composite)%253B%250D%250Ablocker.set(%257Bcolor%253A%2520'black'%252C%2520opacity%253A%25200.3%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btn1%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Button%25201%2522)%253B%250D%250Acomposite.add(btn1%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252010%252C%2520top%253A%252010%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btn2%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Button%25202%2522)%253B%250D%250Acomposite.add(btn2%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252010%252C%2520top%253A%2520100%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btnModal%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Open%2520Modal%2522)%253B%250D%250AbtnModal.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509var%2520win%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Window()%253B%250D%250A%2509win.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Basic())%253B%250D%250A%2509win.addListener(%2522close%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520blocker.unblock()%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509var%2520btnClose%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Close%2520Modal%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnClose.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509win.close()%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509win.add(btnClose)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509desktop.add(win)%253B%250D%250A%2509blocker.block()%253B%250D%250A%2509win.center()%253B%250D%250A%2509win.open()%253B%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250Acomposite.add(btnModal%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252010%252C%2520top%253A%2520200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520pageSecond%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tabview.Page(%2522Second%2522)%253B%250D%250ApageSecond.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Canvas())%253B%250D%250Atabview.add(pageSecond)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btn3%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Button%25203%2522)%253B%250D%250ApageSecond.add(btn3%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%2520100%252C%2520top%253A%252010%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520btn4%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Button%25204%2522)%253B%250D%250ApageSecond.add(btn4%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%2520100%252C%2520top%253A%2520100%257D)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)